# How do I obtain the current release's commit ID during build?

Tags: heroku

I have a Heroku custom buildpack.  I'd like to include the commit ID of the current release in the asset build so that, if the front end reports any errors, we know which version of the code base to check against.

Is there a way to discover the ID of the commit being pushed during the `compile` stage of a heroku build?

Answer (score 0):

What I did recently in my PHP build pack, is that I'm adding a simple date/time string
as an environment variable to the `.profile.d` script. This isn't strongly unique, but should be good enough, because there isn't any real deploy that takes less than a second.

Here's how I generate the `.profile.d/php.sh`:

```
cat > ".profile.d/php.sh" <<SH
export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/app/bin:/app/vendor/nginx/sbin:/app/vendor/php/sbin:/app/vendor/php/bin:/app/vendor/bin:\$PATH
export HEROKU_BUILD_TIME=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
SH

source ".profile.d/php.sh"
```

**Edit:** Sorry, this doesn't solve the problem with having the commit id for debugging. I thought of having a unique string for versioning.